# Write content of div and title in hyperlink at the the same time

Tags: jquery

How do i output content from the div 'wrap_first_btn' AND the value of 'title' from a hyperlink at the same time? The value of 'title' should output inside 'wrap_first_btn' after the content ITEM 1 + image..

I've tried the following code and many combinations, but its not working - do you know how to do it:

JQuery

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var topic = $(this).attr('title') + (span);  // THIS iS NOT WORKING !
        $('#wrap_first_btn').text(topic); 
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" title="ITEM 1">ITEM 1</a> 

<div id="wrap_first_btn"> <span> MAIN MENU </span> <img src="images/arrowhead.png" class="fullscreen_arrow"> </div>
```

Comment: What is the variable `span`?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aFFWL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could separate the text then concatenate them in the output like this

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var topic = $(this).attr('title');
    var text = $('#wrap_first_btn span').html();
    $('#wrap_first_btn span').text(topic + ' ' + text); 
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6km4U/1/)

you could also move the variable declaration outside the click function so you don't re declare every time it is clicked

```
var topic;
var text;
$('a').click(function() {
   topic = $(this).attr('title');
   text = $('#wrap_first_btn span').html();
   $('#wrap_first_btn span').text(topic + ' ' + text); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var topic = $(this).attr('title') + $('#wrap_first_btn').find('span').text();
    $('#wrap_first_btn').text(topic); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
    var topic = $(this).attr('title') + (span);
```

With

```
    var topic = $(this).attr('title') + $("#wrap_first_btn span").html();
```